# Unable to export a tuple to csv/text file using python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, text, tuples

I have a tuple like as shown below

```
vilist = (1,2,3,4)
```

I would like to export this to a text file or csv file

So, I tried the below

```
with open('op.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f , lineterminator='\n')
    for tup in vilist:
        writer.writerow(tup)
```

However, this resulted in error as shown below

```
Error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-cf6cbd3f932b> in <module>
      2     writer = csv.writer(f , lineterminator='\n')
      3     for tup in vilist:
----> 4         writer.writerow(tup)

Error: iterable expected, not numpy.int64
```

I also tried the below

```
vilist.to_csv('test.csv')
```

This also resulted in error.

Can let me know how can I export the tuple to csv?

Comment: If i understand you correctly and that's only one row, you'll need to wrap it within a container like `vilist = ((1,2,3,4), )`

Comment: writerow() is expecting an iterable argument such as a list

Comment: I expect my output to have the values in text file that I can copy and use it in SQL where clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need to pass an iterable to `writerow`, you can simply wrap `tup` in a list:

```
writer.writerow([tup])
```

That is, if you want each tuple element on a separate line. If you want to output the whole tuple to one row, you need to wrap it in a list or a tuple as suggested in the comments.

Comment: thanks, upvoted. I want each element with comma seperated. So, I can use them in where clause of SQL